# mysql fetch data between hours [hh:mm:ss]

Tags: php, mysql, time, hour

Fetch records between hours For example records below, i have tried to fetch the data between morning hours(07:30 to 19:30) and evening hours(19:30 to 07:30), but getting blank results while querying for evening results

```
migi_date|service_number
---------|-------
11:15:00 | 23KPLKS
18:32:42 | KPLSKS3
10:02:04 | OSNSJS0
23:79:00 | QIW8SKD
11:08:00 | 28SOKSL
22:29:00 | 2UJSOPD
```

```
SELECT * FROM `report` WHERE `migi_date` BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '19:30:00';

migi_date|service_number
---------|-------
11:15:00 | 23KPLKS
18:32:42 | KPLSKS3
10:02:04 | OSNSJS0
11:08:00 | 28SOKSL
```

i can able to fetch data between '07:30:00' AND '19:30:00', but for '19:30:00' to '07:30:00' getting blank.

```
using same query with hour change

SELECT * FROM `report` WHERE `migi_date` BETWEEN '19:30:00' AND '07:30:00';
```

Please suggest the query.

Comment: For the evening results you may have to search twice...? From 19:30 to 00:00 then from 00:00 to 7:30....? Maybe not..? It's just an idea, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Between resolves to >=date1 and <=date2 so your second query cannot produce anything , worse though is published data does not establish order of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these two queries could fit...? With the principle that I mentioned in the comment

```
-- Morning
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_hour BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '19:30:00';

-- Evening
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (my_hour BETWEEN '19:30:01' AND '23:59:59') or (my_hour BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '07:29:59');
```

Query built from dummy names.

Answer (score 1):

You should take in consideration the column type.

If your column is time which has range value -838:59:59 to 838:59:59
therefore, you can't expect mysql to use it as 24h round.

@juan is almost right, you need 2 condition

```
`migi_date` BETWEEN '19:30:00' AND '23:59:59'
OR
`migi_date` BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '07:30:00'
```

The same apply if it is a varchar().

You need to adjust seconds if you don't want to have boundaries values in both result

Comment: We had the same idea. With a difference for the seconds but it all depends on what we include in the results :)

Comment: Yes your query do not include boundaries result

Comment: My queries include all data present in the database. But it all depends (for example) if 19:30 should be in the evening or in the morning.

Comment: Exactly with the first query, he gets the 19:30 in the morning, and with your query is (correctly?) excluded.  Without indication, we can't know what is the desired result, 19:30 in the morning or evening? Sometimes, to include boundaries in both is the desired result.

Comment: By the way in your "evening" query there is an error, you should use OR, the value can't be in both interval at the same time.

Comment: Sorry I corrected by replacing "and" with "or" during my tests but I didn't correct when I created the post. Well seen :)

Comment: Good hint regarding the value range of the TIME column type; although if we can assume that only values between `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` will make their way into this table in the first place - because they are meant to be times of the day - then the "extra" conditions are probably not necessary.

Comment: And we agree about boundaries :)

Comment: @CBroe is right `migi_date` >'19:30:00' is sufficient. Another way is: Morning BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '19:30:00'  --- evening NOT BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '19:30:00', but this is not good if you need boundaries in both result